# Use Custom Tiles Across Multiple Web Applications in Different Farms

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem

In the article "Custom Tiles in SharePoint Servers 2016 and 2019"
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/custom-tiles-in-sharepoint-server-2016
it indicates you can use the same custom tiles across multiple web applications.

I was successful in following the article and creating a 'master' custom tiles list and was able to consume it from multiple web applications within the same farm.

I have been able to use the same 'master' tiles for multiple web apps in the same farm.

However, I cannot get other web apps in other farms to use the same 'master' tiles.

Is there a way to have web apps in other farms consume the 'master' tiles list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you must set this up on each farm independently. You could in theory use a workflow to copy the list items from the 'master' to other farms.

Comment: I have confirmed via internally MS resources Custom Tiles cannot be 'consumed' between farms. 

A server side API is used to read the Custom Tiles list, therefore you can't read the Custom Tiles list from sites outside the local farm.